# Construction of a matrix over $ \{-1,0,1\} $

Tags: matrices

Let  $ Z=(z_{ij})  $ be a  $ (n,n)$-matrix, for which:

1. $ z_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}; $
2. $  z_{ij}= -z_{ji} $ for $ i,j=1, \dots , n; $
3. $ \sum_{j=1}^n z_{ij} = 0 $ and $ \sum_{j=1}^n |z_{ij} |>0 $ for $ i=1, \dots , n. $

Please help me to prove that
There exist a  $ (n,n)$-matrix  $ H=(h_{ij}),   $ for which:

1. $ h_{ij} \in \{-1,0, 1\}; $
2. $ h_{ij}= -h_{ji} $ for $ i,j=1, \dots , n; $
3. $ \sum_{j=1}^n h_{ij} = 0 $ and $ \sum_{j=1}^n |h_{ij} |= 2 $ for $ i=1, \dots , n; $
4. $ h_{ij}=1 \Rightarrow z_{ij} >0. $

Comment: What is the link between the matrix $Z$ and the matrix $H$???

Comment: @Martigan The fourth point in the description of $H$, maybe? And it seems that if $Z$ is the zero matrix, you would have trouble finding $H$ so that point $4$ and the second part of $3$ holds simultaneously. Perhaps you mean $h_{ij} = 1 \implies z_{ij} \geq 0$?

Comment: @Arthur I saw the fourth point, which does not explain anything. How can you prove that given there is no relationship between the two matrices... If the matrices are suppose to be similar or something like that, why not, but reading strictly the text does not give any clue to the relationship between the two. We could be speaking of two completly different things...

Comment: @Arthur, thanks. Is it necessary to add the condition $ \sum_{j=1}^n |z_{ij} |>0 $ ?

Comment: @Martigan Yes, $H$ and $Z$ might be completely unrelated, as I see it, except for the fourth point. So this is more of a combinatorics exercise than a linear algebra one.

Comment: Thank you for the discussion. There is another inaccuracy: it must be $ \sum_{j=1}^n |z_{ij} |=c (const) $ , otherwise there are counterexamples for $  n = 4 $. It seems that the problem is known in graph theory.

Answer (score 0):

We can build these matrices recursively.
For $n=2$ we define:

$ M_2 := 
\begin{bmatrix}
   -1  &  1 \\
    1  &  -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Suppose we have defined $M_{n-1}$. We claim that $z_{n-1 n-1}$  element (botom-right element of this matrice) is nonzero. We replace this element by $0$. Hence $z_{n-1 n-1}$ was $\neq 0$, now sum in the last ($n-1$)-th column is $-1$ or $1$.
case A) If it is $-1$, we add the last ($n$-th) row : $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \ldots & 0 & 1 -1   \end{bmatrix}$ and the last ($n$-th) column:

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \ldots \\ 0 \\ 1 \\-1   \end{bmatrix}$ .

case B) If it is $1$, we add the last ($n$-th) row : $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \ldots & 0 & -1 & 1   \end{bmatrix}$ and the last ($n$-th) column:

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \ldots \\ 0 \\ -1 \\1   \end{bmatrix}$ .

And we can see that $z_{n n}$ element is always $\neq 0$ and the summation rules are preserved. Hence this way we define $M_n$ matrix.

For given matrix $Z$ whe have always the same numer of $-1$-s and $1$ in each column (3rd condition).
And also in matrix $M_n$. Number of $0$-s in $M_n$ column  is always greather or equal than numer of $-1$, $1$-s in $Z$.
Hence we can permute each column of $M_n$ in such way we have always $z_{i j} = 1 $ when $h_{i j} > 0 $.

Comment: The point 2 is not satisfied  for $ M_2 $ (?)